# How to make a right pointed arrow using css

Tags: css

I'm creating some custom shapes using CSS I want to draw an arrow whose pointer is on the right side and is aligned left to the div I actually made an arrow which pointer was to the left but I'm having difficulty in making an arrow whose pointer is on right side. 
Here's a picture of how I want it
[arrow](https://i.imgsafe.org/a83890a9d8.png)

Here's my html code

```
<div class="arrow">
   <img style="width:70%" src="https://i.imgsafe.org/a842cd10d7.png" class="img-responsive">
</div>
```

css

```
.arrow {
    position: relative;
}

.arrow::after {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    left: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 18px 30px 18px 0;
    border-color: transparent #fff transparent transparent;
    bottom: 45px;
}
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/jjbftxzs/)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jjbftxzs/3/

Comment: This will do it: https://jsfiddle.net/jjbftxzs/4/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just needed to swap the left/right values of your `border` rules to make the arrow face the opposite direction.

Change this:

```
border-width: 18px 30px 18px 0;
border-color: transparent #fff transparent transparent;
```

To this:

```
border-width: 18px 0 18px 30px;
border-color: transparent transparent transparent #fff;
```

And then to match your example image, I changed the `30px` side to also be `18px`, forming an equilateral triangle.

```css
.arrow {
  position: relative;
}
.arrow::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 18px 0 18px 18px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #fff;
  bottom: 45px;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow">
  <img style="width:70%" src="https://i.imgsafe.org/a842cd10d7.png" class="img-responsive">
</div>
```

Comment: nice one!i tried to do it by your way! anyways thanks..:)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look here I did it (and made arrow in red so it will be easier to see):

```
.arrow {
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px;
}
.arrow::after {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 200;
    content: '';
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    left: 20px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 22px 0 22px 17px;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent red;
    bottom: 62px;
}
```